# extending the string class doesn't work in some context

Tags: typescript

It is possible to extent the type definition of even a builtin type in typescript, for instance this builds, even though out of the box typescript doesn't know a `String.repeat` method:

```
interface String {
    repeat(c: number): string;
}

const spaces = " ".repeat(4);
```

However when I try to apply this pattern in some code of mine, I get a build error:
https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/ng-typeview/blob/c8539fc3403f7e700a023d13655702bdb2113c1b/src/ng-typeview.ts#L18

I get:

```
src/ng-typeview.ts(18,24): error TS2339: Property 'repeat' does not exist on type '" "'.
src/ng-typeview.ts(23,20): error TS2339: Property 'repeat' does not exist on type '" "'.
```

And this, despite the declaration of the extra method lines 12-14.

I tried to simplify the code in that class, or to make the code in my working sample closer to my full code until I isolate what is the thing that breaks the feature, but I didn't get anywhere.

How come the extra interface works in small sample but doesn't in my app? I'm using tsc 2.1.4.

**EDIT**

I cornered the problem further. Exporting an interface in the same file is a minimal reproduction of the issue:

```
interface String {
    repeat(c: number): string;
}

const spaces = " ".repeat(4);


export interface Anything {
    whatever: number;
}
```

Remove the "export" from "export interface" and the problem goes away.

**EDIT2**
Ok now I can't make it work at all with my small sample, extra interface or not. How was it working a little earlier?!?!? So I guess the question could be also reformulated as "is it possible to make typescript accept this method on String keeping an es3 target?". I know it's possible to cast to `any`, would rather avoid it.

Comment: Adding `export` turns your file into 'external module', so the `String` interface in it becomes module-scoped and not global-scoped. Nitzan's answer is correct - if you need to declare something in global scope you have to use `declare global`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you target `es5` then the `repeat` method isn't defined for string, how ever it is [defined in lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4651) so by targeting `es6` the compiler will find it.

If you can't target `es6` you can still use it's lib by specifying it in the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> lib: ["es6"]

If you want to add it yourself then try this:

```
declare global {
    interface String {
        repeat(c: number): string;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's it! for the record. I'm targetting nodejs (6.2.2 on my machine). I'm not sure whether I can actually get the full ES6 on node. I think not. But I can get String.repeat, that works I tested it. It is also not present in the `@types/node` on which I already depend.

Comment: so I'm afraid of adding lib: es6 and then getting runtime errors if the functions are not in fact implemented in node. seems safer to add functions as I test that they're indeed available on node.

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery you should be able to use the typings cli tool to get .d.ts files for node.js 6.9 into your workspace. that may help.

Comment: I wrote lot of extensions and utility and stuff which are heavily coupled based custom extensions.... how should i have both extensions? - PS most of them don't have any equivalent

Comment: @deadManN I don't understand. What do you mean by "both extensions"?

Comment: @NitzanTomer extension coming from tslint and es5, and they wrote, and extension i introduced newly? for string i move a copy of interface to index.d.ts, but for array, it say the Array<T> isn't castable to T[] :| eg. `interface Array<T> { ... Array.prototype.copyArrayFrom = function <T>(sourceArray: Array<T>): void {
  Utility.copyArrayTo<T>(sourceArray, this as Array<T>);
};`  Argument of type 'Array<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T[]'.
  Type 'Array<T>' is missing the following properties from type 'T[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 24 more

Comment: It worked on webstorm and angular 1.x, then i move it to Angular, and changed some code, it worked in the pc i have in my company, then now i fetch my project in home, and it was 6 hours of changing, and still it's broken :| all extensions seem to not work, plus lots of other codes...

Comment: @deadManN I can't understand it when it's written like this in the comments. You better open a new question about your issue, if you think this question is relevant just link to it in your new question.

Comment: it took me a whole day, but i fix all broken changes, the only thing i wish for is when i return to the company after this long vacation, i do not have to revert it all :|

Answer (score 1):

I think the particular error you are dealing with comes from the target value in your tsconfig. When I try es6 as the target .repeat exists, when I do es5 it does not.

Note that if you go-to-definition on the string type, you'll see the declaration typescript is using. It is probably lib.d.ts or lib.es5.d.ts or lib.es6.d.ts (or something else) depending on your tsconfig.

Comment: I don't think so: I reproduced it working and not working with the same tsconfig. My little sample which works did work with the same tsconfig as my app. Also, I managed to find a small sample showing the problem too, updated my question.

Comment: hmm OK now i'm completely confused. Now even my original "always working sample" doesn't work anymore for me. It is true as you said, that selecting an es6 target makes it work even without the extra interface. Adding the extra interface should make it work even forcing an es3 target right, no?

Comment: sorry for the delay, I think Nitzan's got it right. No though; String and string aren't actually the same in typescript.